# Elementry OS works slowly

Tags: elementary-project

My elementary os started to work very slowly.
Is there monitoring tools or any other way I can see why ?
The problem persisted also after reinstalling the OS.
The following is what I did:
1. Install Elementry
2. Install Libre Office
3. Install InSync to google drive
4. Start work on a documents in Libre Office 
In addition all the applications I try to exit say That they cannot exit and ask whether to wait or force quit. 
Ilan

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window and run

> $ htop

Take a look at the process consuming the most amount of CPU time and you might terminate them using the 'kill' command follwoing the proces id, such as:

> $ kill 1234